# Component attributes doesn't set after "reRender" on AJAX request

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, facelets, ajax4jsf

Currently i'm working on some complex web front-end and implement it using:

- JSF 1.2
- Facelets 1.1.15
- RichFaces 3.3.3.Final

I have created a custom JSF component which enables validation of inputText fields using pure JavaScript. This component have only one attribute: type. This attribute is responsible for validation algorithm which will be applied at time when user presses a keyboard key.

At `restoreView` phase when initial view is created this attribute is set by JSF (actually by Facelets). This means that i have a component class with setter and getter for attribute 'type'. And a 'type' setter called with value specified in xhtml document.

Component object is recreated each time at restoreView phase if i specify them in reRender attribute. But when it is recreated my required attribute type is not set. 
It's simply creates new component objects... and it's all. May be i don't understand something and this is normal behavior, but how to get attribute values in this case?

**Code:**

Simple test page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:u="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:r="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:v="http://nobodyhere.ru/jsf/validation">
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:form id="testForm">
            <h:inputText id="textInput" value="test">
                <v:keyValidator type="time"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <a:commandButton value="Make AJAX request" reRender="testForm"/>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Component class:

```
public class KeyValidator extends UIComponentBase
{

    public KeyValidator()
    {
        System.out.println("new KeyValidator");
    }

    public KeyValidatorType getValidatorType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return getValidatorType().toString();
    }

    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = KeyValidatorType.valueOf(type.toUpperCase());
    }

    @Override
    public String getFamily()
    {
        return KeyValidator.class.getName();
    }

    private KeyValidatorType type;
}
```

When i press "Make AJAX request" button my component is recreated. But attribute 'type' is not set in component.

The main problem starts at `renderView` phase in component renderer when `encodeBegin` is called it tries to get this attribute and of course it gets `null` instead of correct value.

So, the more precise question probably:
How to get attribute values of component on AJAX request at `renderView` phase?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override `saveState` and `restoreState` in component to save and restore needed attributes.

Good Luck!